# running sqlite on Oncreate gets error without trace

Tags: android, sqlite

i've been troubled about an error that is occurring in my project and i cant find or trace the error...i just want to clarify if it is possible to do sqlite statement in oncreate or make a method run in oncreate take the code below as example:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        datafromsqlite();
    }

public void datafrom sqlite(){
        Cursor list = DBNAME.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LIST_TBL");
        list.moveToFirst();
        if(list.getCount > 0){
             Log.e(list.getString(1),list.getString(2));
        }else{
             list.close();
    }
}
```

or like this

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

            Cursor list = DBNAME.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LIST_TBL");
            list.moveToFirst();
            if(list.getCount > 0){
                 Log.e(list.getString(1),list.getString(2));
            }else{
                 list.close();
        }
        }
```

UPDATE:

```
@Override
     protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      if (DBNAME.isOpen()) {
          DBNAME.close();
      }
     }
    @Override
     protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      DBNAME = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY 
                  | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);

             }
}
```

Comment: Look here at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: that looks easy to understand thank you for that..

Answer (score 0):

you did not get the database object, you need to create a class that extends the SQLiteOpenHelper class which contains the method getReadableDatabase()

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper dbh=new DbHelper(context);
db=dbh.getReadableDatabase();
```

DbHelper is a class I created that extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: @HakHak what error do you get, is it the same error, have you updated your code ?

Comment: i found a tutorial for sqlite in androidhive and its doing fine..although i had to start from the beginning but now its ok i kind of understand what you are talking about little by little..